# Move result to the right position on table in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

I'm trying to show 7 results on a table (image 1) which I would like to move them to the right position.

Mon = 1 ~ Sun = 7 as we can see on the array and where there is no value I would like to have it $0. At the moment I could not figure out how to move it to the right spot on the table.

[image: image 1]

Here is my code:

```
$w_rep = "SELECT 
      `totals`.`totals_weeknumb`,
      `totals`.`totals_weekday`,
      `totals`.`totals_of_day`
    FROM `totals`
    WHERE `totals`.`totals_has_users_id` = :fromID";
$w_rep_stmt = $DB->prepare($w_rep);
$w_rep_stmt->execute(array(':fromID' => $fromID));
$w_rep_stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$totals_of_day = array();
foreach ($w_rep_stmt as $report) {
    //$tdate = new DateTime($report['totals_date']);
    //$totals_date = $tdate->format('d-m-Y');

    $t_wnumber = (int)$report['totals_weeknumb'];
    $t_wday = (int)$report['totals_weekday'];

    $totals_of_day[$t_wnumber][$t_wday] = (float)$report['totals_of_day'];

    //$sum_of_week[$t_wnumber] = array_sum(array_column($totals_of_day, ''));

} // close foreach

var_dump(array_keys($totals_of_day));
var_dump($totals_of_day);

foreach ($totals_of_day as $w_n => $y) {
?>
<tr>
    <th><?php echo $w_n; ?></th>
    <td><a href="#" title="Click for more details">More Details</a></td>
    <?php
    foreach ($y as $w_day => $saved) {
        echo '<td>'. $curr.number_format($saved, 2) .'</td>';
    } // close foreach
    ?>
    <td><?php //echo $curr.$sum_of_week[]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
} // close 1st foreach
```

I tried so many options :(

Comment: so you are just missing 0$ values?

Comment: Yes and move the result to the right day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to iterate the days of the week and use the index in your array

```
foreach (range(1, 7) as $day) {
    echo (isset($y[$day]) ? $y[$day] : '-');
}
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
$totals_of_day = [
    7 => [3 => 150.8, 4 => 523.88, 5 => 95.32, 7 => 10.8],
    8 => [1 => 13.78, 2 => 107.33, 4 => 8.49, 5 => 125.67],
    9 => [1 => 71.3, 2 => 49.68, 6 => 95, 7 => 100.57],
    10 => [1 => 18.34, 2 => 44.9, 3 => 55.7, 4 => 15.58]
];
?>

<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th>Week</th>
        <th>Items</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Total Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($totals_of_day as $w_n => $y) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $w_n; ?></th>
        <td><a href="#" title="Click for more details">More Details</a></td>
        <?php foreach (range(1, 7) as $day) {
            echo '<td>'. (isset($y[$day]) ? number_format($y[$day], 2) : '-') .'</td>';
        } ?>
        <td><?php echo number_format(array_sum($y), 2); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

[image: example result]

Comment: Woooowwww!!!!!!
That's is amazing, thank you soooooo much....
Você é o cara do PHP.... valeu... Obrigadooooo Sergio...